# script.js:7 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript

This error is breaking my mind, couldn't find anything relevant on Google or on other questions, all that I've found was that it must be a typo or an error with closing brackets but everything is perfect, aparently, I must be missing something really small, here is the code:

```
function Question(question, answers, correct){
    this.question = question;
    this.answers = answers;
    this.correct = correct;
}

Question.prototype.displayQuestion(){
    console.log(this.question);}
```

Comment: Which line is the line 7 in your code? Can you provide a few lines around it, for context?

Comment: Question.prototype.displayQuestion = function () { ...

Comment: Hi, @Dragonthoughts , 
I have commented out the rest of the code, solving one bug at a time, that is all the code I had, the line 7 is 
    Question.prototype.displayQuestion(){
I have solved it by doing
    Question.prototype.displayQuestion = function(){
Which is weird, I was sure that the first attempt was right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code says to invoke Question.prototype.displayQuestion. This is then followed by open curly bracket, which doesn't make sense in this context, hence the error.

```
Question.prototype.displayQuestion(){
  console.log(this.question);}
```

Instead, set Question.prototype.displayQuestion to be a function that you create:

```
Question.prototype.displayQuestion = function () {
  console.log(this.question);
}
```